# make ics file to open iMail program

Tags: icalendar

I uploaded a .ics file on wordpress and created a download link. But when I click download, it opend the file in the browser instead of opening iMail program. What am i missing?

http://cjpfiles.org/?p=299

```
<div class="storycontent">
    <a href="http://cjpfiles.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/TEST-Event.ics">download</a>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your personal pc/browser settings, just like with any other file suffix (.pdf, .jpg etc)

Search for your pc and operating system, with keywords  something like
"default program associate filetype"

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default